# implementing functional interface and passing lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-interface

I have a method with signature `printStudents(List<Student> roster, CheckStudent)` and a functional interface

```
interface CheckStudent {
    boolean test(Student s);
}
```

I  have the following method invocation,

```
printStudents(
    roster,
    (Student s) -> s.getGender() == Student.Sex.MALE
        && s.getAge() >= 18
        && s.getAge() <= 25
);
```

Can we say that the functional interface is implemented? because from my experience we call an interface is implemented when a class implements it, however in this case there is no class implementing it?

My second question,interfaces define functionality and  concrete classes implement the functionality, so in the above case is a class implicitly implementing it or not?

Comment: Add `@FunctionalInterface` annotation to the  `CheckStudent` interface and this is it.

Comment: *because from my experience we call an interface is implemented when a class extends it, however is this case there is no class extending it?* -- I hope you mean implements.

Comment: **"implements"** or not here is just a question of semantics. The fact is that your lambda expression is an instance of `CheckStudent`. Also, please use the built-in `Predicate<Student>` interface instead of writing your own.

Comment: @NicholasK right i mean *implements*